# android display data from database using listview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make simple android app where the user enter his information and then save it in the database and display the user info using listview. I have three java files: DBHelper.java, MainActivity.java and userInfo.java.

(MainActivity.java) is where the user enters his name and email.

(DBHelper.java) is where the database is created to save the user info.

(userInfo.java) is where the user info can be displayed.

in my app I successfully displayed the data from database using textview, and my question is how I can display the data from database using listview.

updated:
this is the getData() method from DBHelper.java file:

```
    public List<Person> getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID2, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL};
    Cursor c = ourDbase.query(TABLE_SCORE, columns, null, null, null, null, null + " DESC");
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iEmail= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setEmail(c.getString(iEmail));
        //set other info, like id, name
        people.add(person); 
    }

    return people;
}
```

here is the Person class:

```
public class Person {
private int ID;
private String NAME;
private String EMAIL;

public Person()
{
    ID=0;
    NAME="";
    EMAIL="";

}
public Person(String qNAME, int qEMAIL) {

    NAME = qNAME;
    EMAIL= qEMAIL;

 }
 public int getID()
 {
    return ID;
 }
 public String getNAME() {
    return NAME;
 }
 public int getEMAIL() {
    return EMAIL;
 }

 public void setID(int id)
 {
    ID=id;
 }
 public void setNAME(String qNAME) {
    NAME = qNAME;
 }
 public void setSCORE(int qEMAIL) {
    EMAIL= qEMAIL;
 }
 }
```

and this is the code where I get the data from database and set it in textview from userInfo.java:

```
   DbHelper userInfo = new DbHelper(this);
    userInfo .open();
    String data = userInfo .getData();
    userInfo .close();
    tv.setText(data);
```

Comment: what adapter u r using to populate listview? BaseAdapter or somthing else?

Comment: @Hirak Chhatbar  I will add the code tom y question

Answer (score 0):

> how I can display the data from database using listview.

Since you dont provide any code about the listview and its adapter, i assume you dont know where to start.

You should create a `listview`, either with custom-created adapter or basic adapter (from android). After that, add the data from the database to your listview's adapter and use `notifyDataSetChanged`() to make sure the data is refreshed on the `listview`.

Simple tutorial : http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

In-depth (**recommended**) tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I saw you a similar question that you answered, and I use it in my code but I didn't know how to display it in userInfo activity, see my updated question.

Comment: @user2521365 (no offense) because you just start learning, i think its better to learn by tutorial i provided you...you will get lost if you dont know the basics.

Comment: @user2521365 Just want to clarify, its not i dont want to help you, but at this rate, its pointless for me to give you some codes because it might work, buy you will not understand it. Please accept my answer if it helps you :)